# Bing Maps How to tell what cluster pin a normal pin is inside

Tags: bing-maps

I'm looking into implementing clustering. We have a list where when an item is clicked we want to center it in the view and pop up an infobox on that pin. Thing is if the pin is currently clustered the infobox is going to appear off position potentially since the cluster is an average position.

Is there a way of getting just clustered pins from the cluster layer?

Found my solution

```
var PinYouAreMatching;//wherever you have this coming from
var primitives = clusterLayer.getPrimitives();
for(var i = 0;i < primitives.length;i++)
{
   if(primitives[i] instanceof Microsoft.Maps.ClusterPushpin)
   {
     var contained = primitives[i].containedPushpins;
     for(var j = 0;j < contained.length;j++)
     {
         if(PinYouAreMatching === contained[j])
         {
            //You found the cluster your pin is at eg. primitives[i].
         }
     }
   }
}
```

You can combine that with references to the cluster on your main pins when your cluster push pin callback to speed things up.

```
function clusterCallBack(cluster)
{
         var contained = primitives[i].containedPushpins;
         for(var j = 0;j < contained.length;j++)
         {
            contained[j].metadata = { cluster: cluster };
         }
}
```

Speeds up some stuff that would O(n^2) or O(n) down to O(n) or O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the event to the clustered pushpin, the event handler will receive the clustered pushpin and you can use it's location to display the infobox. Here is a code sample:

```
clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins, {
    clusteredPinCallback: function(cluster){
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(cluster, 'click', function(e){
            //This is how you get the location of the cluster.
            var loc = e.target.getLocation();

            //Show your infobox here
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this involves a click from the location of the clustered pushpin. I want the click to come from a menu item not directly attached to the map. There is a small enough number of items a linear search should be fine. I just don't see a way to get all current clustered pins from the cluster layer.

Comment: I figured it out, I can use instanceof Microsoft.Maps.ClusterPushpin when going through primitives and I'm good. Also adding some references to the pins when I create my custom cluster push pin for a speed up. Thanks rbrundritt.